Arduino c++ phone toy
Hi i have a problem with my device. I used arduino uno, old keypad, SD card reader, and low quality speaker. Every singel pice works perfectly but all together it doesn't work like i want to. Keypad works sd reader also, and speaker is working but i cant play any sound saved on sd card. I can't find any solution for that.
Im posting my code and picture of device.
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <SD.h>                      // need to include the SD library
//#define SD_ChipSelectPin 53  //example uses hardware SS pin 53 on Mega2560
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4  //using digital pin 4 on arduino nano 328, can use other pins
#include <TMRpcm.h>           //  also need to include this library...
#include <SPI.h>


// C++ code

//#define buzer A0;

TMRpcm tmrpcm;
unsigned long time = 0;


const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {A5, A4, A3, A2};
byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 3, 2, 0};

char keys[ROWS][COLS] ={
    {'3','2','1','a'},
    {'*','0','9','b'},
    {'7','6','5','c'},
    {'.','8',',','d'},
};

Keypad klawiatura = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins,colPins,ROWS,COLS);

String tekst;
const String tel_book[3] = {"","123","321"}; // tu wpisujemy numery pod którymi znajdują sie scieżki dźwiękowe
char* track_list[3] = {"","test.wav","0002.wav"}; // tu wpisujemy nazwy ścieżek dźwiekowych
int lokalizator;

void setup()
{
  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 10; //5,6,11 or 46 on Mega, 9 on Uno, Nano, etc
  //Complimentary Output or Dual Speakers:
  //pinMode(10,OUTPUT); Pin pairs: 9,10 Mega: 5-2,6-7,11-12,46-45 
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT); //LED Connected to analog pin 0 | w sumie to nie wiem ale bez tego nie działa
  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {  // sprawdza czy karta sd jest poprawnie zainstalowana na miejscu
    Serial.println("SD fail");  
    return;   // jeśli nie to wyłącza program

  }
  else{   
    Serial.println("SD ok");
  }
  tmrpcm.volume(4);
  tmrpcm.play("test.wav"); // odgrywa testowy dźwięk po włączeniu urządzenia
  
}

void loop()
{
  char klawisz = klawiatura.getKey(); // pobiera dane z klawiatury i przypisuje do zmiennej
  if (klawisz)
  {
    tekst += klawisz; //wybieranie numeru
    Serial.println(tekst);
    if (tekst.length()==3) // gdy długość numeru jest odpowiednia zaczyna szukac go w książce telefonicznej
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tel_book)/sizeof(*tel_book); i++)
        {
            if (tel_book[i] == tekst)
            {
                lokalizator = i+1; // po znaleziemiu odpowiedniego numeru wybiera jego pozycje z listy
                //Serial.println(i);
                //delay(1000);
                //Serial.println(lokalizator);
                Serial.println("corect num");
                tekst = "";
                return;
            }else{
              tmrpcm.play("0001.wav");// odtworzenie informacji o błednie wybranym numerze
              Serial.println("wrong num");
              lokalizator = 0;
              tekst = "";
              return; 
            }
            
        }
           // wcześniej odnaleziony numer inicjuje odtworzenie odpowiedniej ścieżki dźwiękowej
      tmrpcm.play(track_list[lokalizator]); // to powinno już działac ale jeszcze nie wiem czy tak jak chce  
      tekst = "";
    }
    
  }
  

}

updated acording to comments.
https://i.sstatic.net/IYXu7yVW.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/6hqSrjBM.png

You use D0 in the colPins, but Serial uses that pin also. You define COLS = 4  but keys only has 3 columns. Also you didn't post the serial monitor output. Also we don't know what format your WAV file is in, since the TMRpcm library only accepts unsigned 8 bit PCM with 16khz recommended frequency (https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki)

You also call tmrpcm.play(track_list[lokalizator]); every time in loop, but you should only call it once (if (tel_book[i] == tekst)).

@MaximilianGerhardt thx for pointing it i didn't noticed it

@MaximilianGerhardt i did the corect formating of wav filles all of them are 8bit and 16khz. this weird declaration of cols = 4 it is because on the keypad i have writen 1r 2r 3r 4r 4k 3k 2k 1k so i did it exacly the same and it's working.

it is my first post in here so i have no idea how to use this webside

Does the example work fine? https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/blob/master/examples/basic/basic.ino and put the "music" file from here onto the SD card.

@MaximilianGerhardt yes examples from library works. now when i changed the place of this i can hear the test soundtmrpcm.play(track_list[lokalizator]);but still i cant select the other sounds by keypad

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tel_book); i++) should be for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tel_book)/sizeof(*tel_book); i++). Please update your code, edit the question with your current code and post the serial monitor output.

@MaximilianGerhardt now i did some changes(also your suggests) but all the time i get an error wrong number even i type correct one

Your logic is wrong in the for loop for checking the numbers. If the number doesn't match, it might maybe match in the next iteration. But you immediately return and play the error tone. You must keep going though. Check out https://pastebin.com/ruVsREjk

@MaximilianGerhardt thx mate i was doing for 2weeks and it's finaly working. I realy appreciate your help.

Main issue with the
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tel_book)/sizeof(*tel_book); i++)
        {
            if (tel_book[i] == tekst)
            {
                lokalizator = i+1; // po znaleziemiu odpowiedniego numeru wybiera jego pozycje z listy
                //Serial.println(i);
                //delay(1000);
                //Serial.println(lokalizator);
                Serial.println("corect num");
                tekst = "";
                return;
            }else{
              tmrpcm.play("0001.wav");// odtworzenie informacji o błednie wybranym numerze
              Serial.println("wrong num");
              lokalizator = 0;
              tekst = "";
              return; 
            }
            
        }

Is that this doesn't properly check the tekst input string agianst all known entries in the telephone book. When the first entry doesn't match the input text, it immediately plays the error sound and does a return. Thus it neglects that the tekst could match a later entry in the telephone book. The loop should not immediately abort in the "non-matching" case.
Instead:
      bool foundNumber = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tel_book)/sizeof(*tel_book); i++) 
      {
        Serial.println("Checking input " + tekst + " against number " + tel_book[i]);
        if (tel_book[i] == tekst)
        {
          Serial.println("correct num");
          tmrpcm.play(track_list[i]);
          foundNumber = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!foundNumber) { 
        tmrpcm.play("0001.wav");// odtworzenie informacji o błednie wybranym numerze
        Serial.println("wrong num");
      }
      // reset variables
      tekst = "";

